# Use line break in Linux command

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I'm trying to run a command in a command line (just copy and paste the into moba xterm to remote Ubuntu machine). The command contains a line break, so I decided to use $(command). Here is the command I am trying:

```
docker build -t mytag --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=$(cat <<EOF
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAy8QlGkj4OoK4/i3Sxhpag4k/S/SsDzjMwqM2Sc5qeE2EpuqH
@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^%&(&)@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^%&(&)@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^
@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^%&(&)@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^%&(&)@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^
@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^%&(&)@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^%&(&)@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^
@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^%&(&)@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^%&(&)@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^
KaAM3nF1tnWa1YhDRxOGaq6386hEdB/i05ZFdLjfSALo56UN7mC5
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
EOF
) .
```

I must paste an ssh key into the command somehow. 
The above command is not working; I get:

```
bad flag syntax: -----END
See 'docker build --help'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the key consists of multiple words,
you must put the command substitution into quotes:

```
docker build -t mytag --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat << EOF
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAy8QlGkj4OoK4/i3Sxhpag4k/S/SsDzjMwqM2Sc5qeE2EpuqH
@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^%&(&)@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^%&(&)@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^
@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^%&(&)@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^%&(&)@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^
@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^%&(&)@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^%&(&)@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^
@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^%&(&)@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^%&(&)@#$%$#^$%&^%*&^*&^
KaAM3nF1tnWa1YhDRxOGaq6386hEdB/i05ZFdLjfSALo56UN7mC5
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
EOF
)" .
```

Comment: You might also want to quote the heredoc to protect it from expansions: `<<'EOF'`

Comment: Or just `... SSH_PRIVATE_KEY='multi-line string here'`, without a here-document.